# Is Heidegger's concept of poiēsis different from Aristotle's?

Tags: philosophy-of-technology

First of all, sorry if this question's pretty naive. I am new to Philosophy and I would like to know whether there is a distinction between Aristotle's concept of poiesis and Martin Heidegger's.

Comment: Heidegger's concepts *are* different. Full stop ;) I have yet to encounter any concept he had taken from another author that does not have a different but similar meaning, even though he pretends this was what they really meant all along

Answer (score 1):

According to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poiesis):

> Aristotle considers poiesis as an imitation of physis. In short, the form or idea, which precedes the physis, contrasts with the living, which is the innate principle or form of self-motion. In other words, the technomorphic paradigm contrasts with the biomorphic; the theory of nature as a whole with the theory of the living individual.

> Martin Heidegger refers to it as a 'bringing-forth' (physis as emergence), using this term in its widest sense. He explained poiesis as the blooming of the blossom, the coming-out of a butterfly from a cocoon, the plummeting of a waterfall when the snow begins to melt. The last two analogies underline Heidegger's example of a threshold occasion: a moment of ecstasis when something moves away from its standing as one thing to become another. (These examples may also be understood as the unfolding of a thing out of itself, as being discloses or gathers from nothing [thus nothing is thought also as being]). Additional example: The night gathers at the close of day.

In summary, Aristotle's interpretation is literally the form preceding the self-moved living while Heidegger's interpretation is [hermeneutic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics#Heidegger_(1889%E2%80%931976)):

> In the 20th century, Martin Heidegger's philosophical hermeneutics shifted the focus from interpretation to existential understanding as rooted in fundamental ontology, which was treated more as a direct—and thus more authentic—way of being-in-the-world (In-der-Welt-sein) than merely as "a way of knowing." For example, he called for a "special hermeneutic of empathy" to dissolve the classic philosophic issue of "other minds" by putting the issue in the context of the being-with of human relatedness. (Heidegger himself did not complete this inquiry.)

> Advocates of this approach claim that some texts, and the people who produce them, cannot be studied by means of using the same scientific methods that are used in the natural sciences, thus drawing upon arguments similar to those of antipositivism. Moreover, they claim that such texts are conventionalized expressions of the experience of the author. Thus, the interpretation of such texts will reveal something about the social context in which they were formed, and, more significantly, will provide the reader with a means of sharing the experiences of the author.

> The reciprocity between text and context is part of what Heidegger called the hermeneutic circle. Among the key thinkers who elaborated this idea was the sociologist Max Weber.